# Powershell Add-Content should create path but throws exception "Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: powershell

I'm using the powershell `Add-Content` to create a file. However, when the folder of the file does not exist I get an error:

`Add-Content : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\tests\test134\logs\test134.log'.`

According to the documentation this should create the folder:

```
PS C:\> Add-Content -Value (Get-Content "test.log") -Path  "C:\tests\test134\logs\test134.log"
```

> This command creates a new
>   directory and file and copies the content of an existing file to the
>   newly created file.
>
> This command uses the Add-Content cmdlet to add the content. The value
>   of the Value parameter is a Get-Content command that gets content from
>   an existing file, Test.log.
>
> The value of the path parameter is a path that does not exist when the
>   command runs. In this example, only the C:\Tests directories exist.
>   The command creates the remaining directories and the Test134.log
>   file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-5.1

Seems like an clear issue in Add-Content, doesn't it?
Can you reproduce this?

edit: I'm running PowerShell version 5.1.16299.64

BR Matthias

Comment: Methinks the documentation is missing a piece of the snippet. As the verb implies; it `Add`s content [to an existing item]

Comment: I opened an issue: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33062206-add-content-should-create-folder-but-returns-error

Comment: What is your PowerShell version. Are you running 5.1? This is important and not explicit in your question or bug report.

Comment: Good point. I'm running 5.1.16299.64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Add-Content` cmdlet can't create the path but only the file. It works:

```
$Path = "C:\tests\test134\logs2\test134.log"
$Path |% { 
           If (Test-Path -Path $_) { Get-Item $_ } 
           Else { New-Item -Path $_ -Force } 
} | Add-Content -Value 'sample content'
```

Answer (score 6):

Just another alternative:

```
$Path = "C:\tests\test134\logs2\test134.log"
If (!(Test-Path $Path)) {New-Item -Path $Path -Force}
Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "Sample Content"
```

Comment: Even if this is the same answer as @fdafadf, I find this solution more human readable